# How to display a misclassified image?

Tags: tensorflow

In a general training pipeline of TensorFlow, how is it possible to print (perhaps by means of TensorBoard) misclassified examples/images?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're using a softmax classifer that selects between N classes as the last layer of your network. Pseudo code might look like this, where the final layer has batch size as its first dimension:

```
# computation graph
predictions = argmax(softmax(final_layer))
matches = predictions == argmax(labels) # if one-hot encoded

# later
batch_matches = sess.run(matches, feed_dict={...})

for image, does_match in zip(batch_images, batch_matches):
  if not does_match:
    cv2.imwrite('mismatched.png', image)
```